# Write a listener application for Azure Service Bus Queue

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-servicebus-queues

I need to have a listener app in .NET Core which will continuously look into new messages in Azure Service Bus Queue. I've tried so far with different approaches, but only able to read messages from ASB queue which are already published to queue before my listener application has started consuming. But once all the existing messages are processed and then the listener is not able to read any new messages from ASB queue.

I'm trying to figure out whether there is any method in the namespace "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" which will continuously pull messages from ASB queue.

I do not want to create a WHILE loop or a long running Task.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried ```IHostedService``` like described [here](https://damienbod.com/2021/07/20/using-an-asp-net-core-ihostedservice-to-run-azure-service-bus-subscriptions-and-consumers/)?

Comment: [Write a listener application for an Azure solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/write-listener-application-azure-solution)

Comment: @Martin I've checked that option, but as i've mentioned in my question, i'm looking for something inbuilt in the library in "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" instead of taking advantage of IHostedService.

Comment: The built-in way is the receive message handler. Which must then be hosted in sth. like a IHostedService :)

Answer (score -1):

There are 4 ways to create an "**Azure Service Bus Queue**". This could be the long procedure to understand. To make it precise, I am attaching the links to follow for different methods of creation.

**ARM Template :** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-resource-manager-namespace-queue

**Powershell:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quickstart-powershell

**Azure CLI:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quickstart-cli

**Azure Portal:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quickstart-portal

The Suitable answer for the requirement:

- The receive modes are two types.

  - Receive and Delete
  - Peek lock

We can receive the message and pull it to read using **`Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`** as required. Using the namespaces and utilizing the services of [Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues#receive-messages-from-the-queue)